# How can I access the attributes of a <span> element inside of an asp.net RepeaterItem?

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I'm trying to alter the CSS class of a span that is positioned within an Asp.net `RepeaterItem`. The `span` element also has other tags inside of it (radio button).

The markup is similar to this:

```
<asp:Repeater>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <span class="spanClass" runat="server">
            <label>
                <asp:RadioButton id="rbID">
                </asp:RadioButton>
            </label>
        </span>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I'm able to edit the radio button by using the following:

```
rb = (RadioButton)(repeaterItem.FindControl("rbID");
rb.Checked = true;
//this works
```

However, when using a similar piece of code to grab the `span`, it fails with an `InnerHtml exception` because the `span` is not a literal control:

```
span = (GenericHtmlControl)(repeaterItem.FindControl("spanID");
span.Attributes.Add("class", "ClassToAdd");
//this fails
```

The reading I've done says that this is the case because the `span` is not a literal control because it has other server controls within it (the radio button).

Is there a way to access the attributes of the `<span>` in question?

Answer (score 6):

Change your `span` like this:

```
<span id="spanID" runat="server">
```

and then this in your code behind:

```
protected void myRep_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        HtmlGenericControl x = (HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("spanID");
        x.Attributes["class"] = "myClass";
    }

}
```

Comment: Quick caveat: If you are referencing the span by id in your javascript, you will need to take into account the span ids will now be different.

Comment: Indeed. Good thing Asp.net will create the ids for us :D

Comment: Sorry for the delay, and I forgot to include in my original code that I already have the runat property set for the span.  I will try it onItemDataBound in the morning.

Comment: I still get the InnerHtml Exception when trying to access the span on ItemDataBound with runat="server"

Comment: I ran and tested the code I gave you and I get no errors. Are you sure nothing else is giving you this error?

Comment: No matter how I ran tried to access the span, it complained about it not being a literal control (due to the radio button nested inside of it).  I ended up just using inline code in the .ascx to set the class attribute of the span.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a field called "ClassToAdd" to the collection you are binding to the repeater.  Then simply use Eval to display it. (For example, if you are binding the repeater to a DataTable, you could add a new Column called ClassToAdd and set the values appropriately in the code behind.)

```
<asp:Repeater>
    <ItemTemplate> 
        <span class="<%#Eval("ClassToAdd")%>"> 
        </span>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```